JPA Console Unable to locate persistence units
go to Persistence view in IDE options
run JPA console
I'm using the IDE's persist option
see the error below
completed in 1 s 723 ms

[2024-04-25 10:59:03] Unable to locate persistence units
[2024-04-25 10:59:03] jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
[2024-04-25 10:59:03] Error parsing XML [line : -1, column : -1] : cvc-elt.1.a: Não foi possível encontrar a declaração do elemento 'persistence'.

My Persister Settings
Follow my project settings
I'm using JAVA 17 and hibernate with Oracle.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="3.1" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="syacwebPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <!--<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
            <!--<property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="20"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20"/>
            <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_statement"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.handling_mode" value="delayed_acquisition_and_release_after_transaction" />
            <property name="hibernate.criteria.literal_handling_mode" value="BIND" />
            <property name="hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.query.fail_on_pagination_over_collection_fetch" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>

            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.session.events.log" value="false"/>

            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
                      value="org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.javax.cache.provider" value="org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider"/>
            <property name="net.sf.ehcache.config.PersistenceConfiguration.Strategy" value="localTempSwap"/>
            <property name="hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy" value="create"/>
            <!--<prop<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="META-INF/ehcache.xml"/>-->

            <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA"/>
            <property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider"
                      value="com.j2system.syacweb.multiTenant.SchemaMultiTenantConnectionProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver"
                      value="com.j2system.syacweb.multiTenant.SchemaCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver"/>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout" value="60000" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.maxLifetime" value="60000" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.validationTimeout" value="50000" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.leakDetectionThreshold" value="60000" />

            <!-- ensure backward compatibility -->
            <property name="hibernate.type.preferred_duration_jdbc_type" value="BIGINT" />
            <property name="hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type" value="TIMESTAMP" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>

Run JPA queries directly from Intelij
If anyone can help me I would be grateful, thank you

Did you configure it in IntelliJ IDEA settings? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/persistence-tool-window.html.
